# WITH EXECUTE AS 'dbo' causing the error Invoke-Sqlcmd : Only active directory users can impersonate other active directory users Azure SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I recently restored a copy of a SQL server database in azure onto a different database server, on running a stored procedure that previously worked without issues, I started getting the error message below after running the stored procedure using sql-cmd via powershell.

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "exec dbo.sp_test 'Tom Jerry', 'test@test.com', 'fsf87901-gh12-400e-89nk-1f893cg923f1', 'Testing'" -ServerInstance database-server -Database test-db -Username test-user -Password test-password
```

The stored procedure `sp_test`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_test]
    (@name varchar(100),
     @email varchar(200),
     @guid varchar(100),
     @campaign varchar(100))
WITH EXECUTE AS 'dbo'
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT @name, @email, @guid, @campaign
END
GO
```

I get this error:

> Invoke-Sqlcmd : Only Active Directory users can impersonate other Active Directory users.
> At line:1 char:1
>
> - Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "exec dbo.sp_test 'Tom Jerry', ...
> - CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], SqlPowerShellSqlExecutionException
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlError,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand

What is causing the error is the addition of the below.

```
WITH EXECUTE AS 'dbo'
```

As I inherited the setup, I am worried about removing the line and what the consequences could be. Does anyone know why this is in use and why I could be getting the issue on a restored copy of the database, if the stored procedure is created on an existing database, I do not get the error the stored procedure works as it should.

Comment: Who is the owner of the database? Presumably the owner is an AD Account.

Comment: @Larnu owner is a sql server login which is an admin user.

Comment: After restoring the database backup to a different instance did you link the database users to the same Windows/AD logins and SQL Logins to which they were linked on the original server?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the issue. There are 2 issues that needs resolving.

The admin login for the server, let us call it admin_login. I created a user on the database with dbo rights. To fix the issue.

drop the user admin_login

```
drop user [admin-login-sit]
```

set the login as the database owner.

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::[my_database] TO [admin_login]
```

The above fixed the issue for me.